# Gradle will not publish artifact?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Gradle v4.10.2

I’m building a Gradle Java plugin, and it builds. However when I run `./gradlew publish` it does nothing, i.e., the artifact doesn’t get published. Here’s my `build.gradle` file (I have all the variables defined in my `gradle.properties` file). Also, if I just run `./gradlew publish` w/o running `./gradlew build` first, it doesn’t run the build phase. What am I missing in my `build.gradle` file? Thanks.

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'maven'
  id 'maven-publish'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group=project.groupId
version = '0.0.1'

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'artifactId': project.artifactId,
               'groupId': project.groupId,
               'version': project.version
  }
  baseName artifactId
  doLast {
    println "artifactId: $project.artifactId\ngroupId: $project.groupId\nversion: $version"
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile gradleApi()
}

// For publishigh to S3 maven repo
publishing {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "s3://" + s3_bucket
      credentials(AwsCredentials) {
        accessKey AWS_ACCESS_KEY
        secretKey AWS_SECRET_KEY
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTFM. I was missing the publications block inside the publishing block. Here’s the whole block

```
publishing {
  publications {
    myLibrary(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java
    }
  }
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "s3://" + s3_bucket
      credentials(AwsCredentials) {
        accessKey AWS_ACCESS_KEY
        secretKey AWS_SECRET_KEY
      }
    }
  }
}
```